# How can I send an sms in Android after a user-designated amount of time?

Tags: java, android, sms, alarmmanager

I would first like to appologize that I am new to Android developement, and the answer may be much simpler than I realize.

The issue I am having is that for the program I am working on, I need my app to send a text message after a certain amount of time that the user chooses, to a phone number they choose. >I know how to use `sendSMS("1234445555", "Message");`

But how can I make it run so that the message will be sent, even if the app doesn't have focus, or if the phone is currently asleep? Also, is there any way to allow the user to go back to the app and cancel the message before the timer they set runs out?

Comment: Yes, all of these things are possible, you should read about creating a background service in Android, that service will call sendSMS method to send sms if a particular flag is set to true. If user wants to override that, he can open the foreground application and override that flat to false and sms will not be sent by the service,

Comment: A background `Service` is huge overkill for this. Schedule your task with [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at android Task Scheduling.
You can use Schedule Task, Alarm Manager or JobScheduler and write the message sending code in a service

Have a look at following link.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: I actually looked at that website a few times, but was unsure how to use the Alarm Manager to schedule a non-repetitive action as well as cancelling the action once it was started. Am I missing something on that page?

Comment: AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)